# Selenium: Find an element stored in a container

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium to automate a processes. I've had a lot of success being able to find what I need here so far, but was unable to find a way to locate this element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AUL.update('AssignedAssetsUpdateContainer', {}, '13.7.25.0.0.0.0.2.3.0.0.1.2.0.3.0.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.5.1.19.0.1.3.1');">
123456
</a>
```

I first attempted to look for it by searching all tags like so:

```
assetElements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for element in assetElements:
     if(element.text == "123456")
          element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I chose this route obviously because of the href tag, but it tells me that it can't find the element on the page. I think that this is because the page is querying a database and populating it in a container.

Butttt.... Out of sheer drive to find it, I took the additional find_elements options found on https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html# and printed out their .text segments where available and was unable to find it.

Any ideas would be welcome. It is my first time posting on the site so I hope I didn't miss anything.

Here is an image of the field I'm attempting to locate, its a search response:

**Search Field Container Response**

[image: Screen Shot]

for the sake of showing, here is the CSS response finding the other entries but not "123456"

**CSS_Selector Response**

[image: Screen Shot]

Added Screenshot showing the found results searching the elements

**Screen Shot of Found Element @JeffC**

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Did you try by link text or partial link text? You can also use an XPath like `//a[.='123456']` or maybe `//a[contains(.,'123456')]`. You could also try something like a CSS selector, `a[onclick*='AssignedAssetsUpdateContainer']`

Comment: I did attempt with find_elements_xpath and I return no results, using CSS Selector will return the other entries on the list expect the one "123456" in the container. @JeffC

Comment: Did you try adding a wait? Wait for something that is the last thing to load on the page. Then try the locators again. You should try waiting for the page to load and then using `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPath in the browser console... does it find them then?

Comment: Hey @JeffC Thank you for you're time and responses, I'm actually not familiar with using the browser console. I just tried and "//a[contains(.,'123456')]" does find it no problem there.





  assetNumberElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'123456')]")



returns





selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'123456')]"}

Comment: The dev tools panel can be opened using F12. From there, open the Console and type the command, e.g. `$$("a[onclick*='AssignedAssetsUpdateContainer']")` as an example CSS selector or `$x("//a[.='123456']")` as an example XPath. See more help on the Chrome console [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/), especially the Command Line Reference page.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm finding an element and sending keys to the element. assetElements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") then proceed to send a key to it. In this case Return, sorry if I miss communicated this.

Comment: @JeffC I've attached a screenshot where I was able to find it searching, but $$() and $x() in the console don't show results found

Comment: @RobertKruger You can't `sendKeys` to a `<a>` tag but you can `click` it. `sendKeys` can be invoked only on `<input>` elements. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'AssignedAssetsUpdateContainer') and normalize-space()='123456']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```